# Translating “About that...”

Tags: expressions, traduction

How would you translate “About that...” in the context of regretting that something happened or not wanting to admit something related to the topic at hand?

*“I’m going to bring my new blender to the neighbor’s to let them borrow it. Could you grab it for me?”*

*“About that... I accidentally broke it.”*

or:

*“I can’t wait to go on this date... he’s perfect!”*

*“Yeah, about that... I saw him kissing someone else yesterday.”*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say `À ce propos...` or `À ce sujet...` (I'd use more naturally the former)

It's quite usual in French and conveys the same idea of embarrassment as in English (contrary to the simple `Au fait` which is neutral). And it is quite a similar construction as in English, so easy to remember.

Comment: If I may add, in the orale form, I'd say *À propos de ça...*, a little bit more colloquial form.

Comment: You can also use simply *justement*. Or a bit more elaborate: *puisque tu en parles* ou *je voulais t'en parler*

Answer (score -3):

In the first case "Ça alors !" can be used among other locutions ;

- Ça alors ! Par mégarde je viens de le casser …
- Ça alors ! Par maladresse je viens de le casser …
- Zut (alors) ! Je viens de le casser en n'y faisant pas assez attention. *informal, but current*

In the second "ça alors" won't do ; here are two possibilities among a whole lot of them ;

- Oh ! oui, en parlant de perfection … Je l'ai vu hier en train d'embrasser quelqu'un d'autre.
- Oui, en effet, ô combien parfait, je l'ai vu hier en train d'embrasser quelqu'un d'autre.

Comment: IMHO, `ça alors` might be used in the same situation but it conveys surprise, not the same feeling of regret or embarrassment as `About that`. It is more an equivalent of `My goodness!`.  For the second sentence, your `en parlant de...` is a nice idea, but `Combien parfait` seems awkward.

Comment: @Steph Je ne crois pas, je ne suis pas énormément familier avec les formes de ce type, mais je pensais pouvoir en utiliser sans vérification. Je viens de faire une vérification et je crois qu'il n'y aucun problème; voyez ce que vous en pensez : [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/oh+combien+difficile.html).

Comment: "Oh! Combien parfait !" ne se dit pas. Les exemples trouvés dans Linguee qui utilisent "oh" avant "combien + adjectif"  (p.ex. "une situation oh combien difficiles) sont des erreurs d'orthographe et devraient être "ô combien". Mais cette locution ne s'utilise jamais en début de phrase. http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/oh-combien-a93407619

Comment: @Greg Merci pour ces explications incontournables.